# How can I save a word file in dotx format using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, converters, docx

On my work i need to create a lot do**t**x file for specialized program with some typical data. I try to use popular libraries like **docxtpl** or **python-docx**, but as I understand it, they do not support work with **dotx** files. I try Aspose.Words and Spire.Doc libraries but it not free and create watermarks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckeXj.png)

I need a way to open dotx files and edit it, or at least save docx files in dotx format using Python on Windows.

Is there any free libraries or addons that can resolve my problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer and removed older answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Yes, spire.doc module is a paid version. After seeing your comment, I checked whether it is possible with any other module. It works with python-docx

Installation:

```
pip3 install python-docx #if python3
pip install python-docx # if python2
```

Usage:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
doc.save('test.dotx')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this now. But this API like Aspose's create a watermark on free version.

Comment: @matwej, I've edited my answer and removed older answer

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this library does not create dotx file this way.  it do it like i rename existing docx word file in Windows Explorer as dotx. It corrupt file and it doesnt open.

Comment: Mine is linux and it works well in linux.

Answer (score 0):

i find solution on original project on github. For windows we need to add only 2 strings.

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
document_part = document.part
document_part._content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml'
doc.save('test.dotx')
```